# drupal custom settings page

Tags: php, drupal

I am trying to make a custom settings page for my custom module.

here is my file setup:

[image]

**burnblock_hooks.settings.yml**

```
burnblock_hooks:
  name: 'Hank Williams'
```

**burnblock_hooks.module:**

```
function defaultConfiguration() {
    $default_config = \Drupal::config('burnblock_hooks.settings');
    return [
        'hello_block_name' => $default_config->get('hello.name'),
    ];
}
```

After installing this i don't see anywhere the configuration page

Can anyone see what ive done wrong?

Comment: What is your Drupal version?

Comment: If 8, see this: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/form-api/configformbase-with-simple-configuration-api